# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5) (3,)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I have 15 ode equations need to be solved simultaneously and I want to solve them using solve_ivp.

There are each 5 states for T, co2, and q. The initial conditions are T=20, co2 = 0, q=0

I tried to separate them into 3 lists, one for T, one for co2, and one for q.

I am not sure how to resolve this bug and have worked on it for couple hours.
Really appreciate your help!

```
import math
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from bokeh.core.property.instance import Instance
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.model import Model
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, Callback
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show
import numpy as np

# three plots , co2 as y and z as x

###############    User generated - Slider initial value   ############### 
V= 100.0 # volume
r = 5.0
T = 20.0
c_co2_0 = 5.0 # concentration
episl_r = 0.3 # void
v0 = 2.0 # initial vilocity

###############  ---          Static Parameters        ---  ############### 
b0 = 93.0 * (10**(-5))
deltH_0 = 95.3 # calculate b
Tw = -5.0 # room temperature
T0 = 353.15 # temeperature 
t0 = .37 # heterogeneity constant, in paper is denoted as t_h0
alpha = 0.33
chi = 0.0 
q_s0 = 3.40
R = 8.314
kT = 3.5*(10**3) #calculate rA
ρs = 880.0
deltH_co2 = 75.0 # calculate temeprature change 

# ------------------ For Equation 4 : Enegergy Ballance  --------------
ρg = 1.87 # ?
h = 13.8
Cp_g = 37.55 # J/molK
Cp_s = 1580.0 # J/molK

###############   -----  Parameters depend on input  -----  ############### 
L = V / (math.pi * r**2)
deltZ = L / 5.0 # 5 boxes in total
p_co2 = R * T * c_co2_0
a_s = deltZ / r
theta = (1-episl_r) * ρs * Cp_s +  episl_r * ρg * Cp_g

# Equations are calclulated in order 
def b(T):
    b = ( b0 ** ( (deltH_0/ (R * T0) ) * (T0/T - 1) ) )
    return b

def t_h(T):
    return ( t0 + alpha * (1 - T0 / T) )

def q_s(T):
    return ( q_s0 ** ( chi * (1 - T / T0)) )

# Calculate rco2_n (not ode)
# change it to q
def R_co2(T, c_co2, q): 
    b_var = b(T)
    t_var = t_h(T)
    qs_var = q_s(T)
    # print(qs_var)
    r_co2 =  kT * ( R * T * c_co2 * ( (1- ( (q / qs_var)**t_var) )**(1/t_var) ) - q / (b_var*qs_var) ) 
    # print(r_co2)
    return r_co2
# ODE Part 
# Repetitive shortcut

# Equation 2
ener_balan_part1 = v0  * ρg* Cp_g 
def ener_balan(theta, deltZ): # replace v0  * ρg* Cp_g / (theta * deltZ) 
    return(ener_balan_part1/ (theta*deltZ) )
def ener_balan2(episl_r):
    return( (1-episl_r) * ρs * deltH_co2)
def ener_balan3(a_s, Tw, T0):
    return (a_s * h *(Tw-T0))

# Equation 1 Mass Balance : find co2_n

def mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ):
    return ( v0/ (episl_r * deltZ) )
def masss_balan2(episl_r, ρs):
    return( (1-episl_r ) * ρs )
def deriv(t, y):
    T_n, co2_n, q_n = y
    # rco2_ first, rate of generation 
    T1 = -ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T_n + ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T0 + ener_balan2(episl_r)* (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n))+ ener_balan3(a_s, Tw, T0)
    co2_1 = -mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * co2_n + mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * c_co2_0 - (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)) * masss_balan2(episl_r, ρs)
    q_1 = R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)

    T2 = -ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T_n + ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T0 + ener_balan2(episl_r)* (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n))+ ener_balan3(a_s, Tw, T0)
    co2_2 = -mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * co2_n + mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * c_co2_0 - (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)) * masss_balan2(episl_r, ρs)
    q_2 = R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)

    T3 = -ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T_n + ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T0 + ener_balan2(episl_r)* (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n))+ ener_balan3(a_s, Tw, T0)
    co2_3 = -mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * co2_n + mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * c_co2_0 - (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)) * masss_balan2(episl_r, ρs)
    q_3 = R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)

    T4 = -ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T_n + ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T0 + ener_balan2(episl_r)* (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n))+ ener_balan3(a_s, Tw, T0)
    co2_4 = -mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * co2_n + mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * c_co2_0 - (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)) * masss_balan2(episl_r, ρs)
    q_4 = R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)

    T5 = -ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T_n + ener_balan(theta, deltZ) * T0 + ener_balan2(episl_r)* (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n))+ ener_balan3(a_s, Tw, T0)
    co2_5 = -mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * co2_n + mass_balan(episl_r, deltZ) * c_co2_0 - (R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)) * masss_balan2(episl_r, ρs)
    q_5 = R_co2(T_n, co2_n, q_n)

    T_ls = np.array([T1, T2, T3, T4, T5])
    co2_ls = np.array([co2_1, co2_2, co2_3, co2_4, co2_5])
    q_ls = np.array([q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5])

    return T_ls, co2_ls, q_ls
    
t0, tf = 0, 10
############# initial condition 
T_initial = 20
c_co2_0 = 0
q0 = 0
init_cond = np.array([20, 0, 0])
N=5
soln = solve_ivp(deriv, (t0, tf), init_cond)
```

Here is the error message

```
helper.py:293: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  r_co2 =  kT * ( R * T * c_co2 * ( (1- ( (q / qs_var)**t_var) )**(1/t_var) ) - q / (b_var*qs_var) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helper.py", line 350, in <module>
    soln = solve_ivp(deriv, (t0, tf), init_cond)
  File "/Users/cocochen/.local/share/virtualenvs/py-HkKPxrQC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py", line 546, in solve_ivp
    solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
  File "/Users/cocochen/.local/share/virtualenvs/py-HkKPxrQC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.h_abs = select_initial_step(
  File "/Users/cocochen/.local/share/virtualenvs/py-HkKPxrQC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/common.py", line 104, in select_initial_step
    d1 = norm(f0 / scale)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5) (3,)
```

Comment: Your code contains many variables that you didn't define in the code you shared - please include more code so that your example becomes something people here can run to reproduce the problem you're having - ideally a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but at the very least something reproducible. (specifically, `ener_balan`, `theta`, `deltZ`, etc. are undefined)

Comment: Where's the traceback?  Do you expect us to just guess (or deduce) where the error occurs?  There are lots of places where `broadcasting` can occur, such as addition of 2 arrays.  By the basic rules of `numpy broadcasting`, a (3,5) array cannot work with a (3,) shape.  A (1,5) would work with it, or a (3,1).  Have you spent enough time with the `numpy` basics to understand what we mean by `broadcasting`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Just included more codes.

Comment: Initial condition and `y` has shape (3,).  Looks like `deriv` returns a (3,5) result. Is that consistent with  what `solve_ivp` expects?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example based answer as I recreated the exact error message. So what is the problem here is that you are not following **Numpy broadcasting rules**. Which basically says arrays can be broadcasted (given certain operation) if their **dimensions** are **same** or **equal to 1**.

Lets see an example below with error & solution:

```html
import numpy as np
array_1 = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
array_2 = np.arange(3)
```

**array_1** has shape **(3, 5)**
**array_2** has shape **(3,)**

If you trying to add them (internally it will be broadcasted) using below code

```
array_1 + array_2
```

This will be the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5) (3,)
```

As we are not following above mentioned rules. To resolve this we need to reshape array_2 like this

```
array_2 = array_2.reshape(-1,1)
```

Now if you check, array_2 shape is

```
(3, 1)
```

And now if we try to add both arrays

```
array_1 + array_2
```

It will work because now both of the rules are satisfied, both array either have dimensions or have dimension value as 1 (array_2 shape (3,1))

Comment: I tried it but my variable ```init_cond``` for solve_ivp must be 1-dimensional. It is required by solve_ivp.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: You can do it this way - array_1.reshape(-1,1) + array_2, here array_2 is one dimensional but shape of array_1 is changed to make broadcasting possible.

Comment: please do accept the answer if resolved mentioned query.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

The `fun` argument to `solve_ivp` is specified as

```
The calling signature is fun(t, y). Here t is a scalar, and there are two options for the ndarray y: 
It can either have shape (n,); then fun must return array_like with shape (n,).
```

`y` is `init_cond = np.array([20, 0, 0])`, shape (3,)

That means `deriv` must return a (3,) result.  What is

```
 deriv(0, init_cond)
```

I'm not going download and run your code, but the end of `deriv` is

```
T_ls = np.array([T1, T2, T3, T4, T5])
co2_ls = np.array([co2_1, co2_2, co2_3, co2_4, co2_5])
q_ls = np.array([q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5])
return T_ls, co2_ls, q_ls
```

That creates 3 shape (5,) array, and returns them as tuple.  That makes a (3,5) array.

My guess is that the error point

```
norm(f0 / scale)
```

`f0` is from a trial `func` run, and hence (3,5), while `scale` is (3,) derived from the `init_cond`.

Failure to read or follow the specifications is a common cause of problems with these `scipy` solve functions (also the optimize and integrate).